# Variational formulation of a PDE on the unit sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I study the following system of equations :

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\partial_t u - d_u \partial^2_{\theta \theta} u &= f(u,v) \quad u \in S(0,1)\\
\partial_t v - d_v \Delta_{x,y} v &= g(u,v) \quad v \in B(0,1)
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

embodied with suitable initial and boundary conditions, for instance of Neumann type:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u(\theta,0) = u_0(\theta) \\
v(x,y,0) = v_0(x,y) \\
\partial_nv(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),t) = u(\theta,t)
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Here $S(0,1)$ denotes the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $B(0,1)$ the unit ball.

I want to establish its variational formulation, and I am struggling with $u$. I don't know in which functional space I should take the test function.